# My ubuntu is not working properly

Tags: 20.04

So I've been using Ubuntu for about a week now, and it's been good so far. However, today it started misbehaving: my keyboard is pressing 'w' by itself, and my mouse isn't moving. What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?"

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It looks like the issue is with your system's hardware. Did you check it with other operating systems??

Comment: Yeah it working fine with windows 10. Before I install it